# Dell Boomi - Only 1 record updating Salesforce at a time

Tags: xml, salesforce, integration, etl, boomi

I'm running into an issue where I'm only receiving 1 Boomi document to send to Salesforce at a time.

Here's the setup:

1. login to Orangelogic
2. Get records (in XML format) from web service
3. Split up the XML response using Data Process
4. Use flow control to group the record into batches
5. Map the web service response to the Salesforce request

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved and had to do with the XML profiles that I created. The node that had to be iterated had a max count of 1. It had to be set to unbounded.